# Rebus with attitude

Tags: rebus

#### What three-word pun is [`rebus`](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebus)ed here?

[image]

```
                ____                     ________________________
   AS TEXT     |1   |                   |2   |3   |    |    |    |
               |  @ |                   |  N |  O |  W |  A |  Y |
               |____|___________________|____|____|____|____|____|     ______________
               |4   |    | 5  |    |    |    |    |                   |6   |7   |    |
               |  ✶ |  H |  O |  L |  E |    |  H |                   |  B |  A |  H |
               |____|____|____|____|____|    |____|          ____     |____|____|____|
               |    |    |    |              |    |         |8   |         |    |
               |  % |    |  R |              |  Y |         |  S |         |  N |
               |____|____|____|______________|____|_________|____|_________|____|     ____
               |9   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |10  |
               |  & |  A |  N |  O |  T |  H |  E |  R |  T |  H |  I |  N |  G |    |  C |
               |____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|    |____|
               |    |    |    |              |    |         |    |         |    |    |    |
               |  # |    |  E |              |  A |         |  U |         |  R |    |  R |
 ______________|____|    |____|              |____|         |____|_________|____|____|____|
|11  |    |    |    |    |    |              |    |         |12  |    |    |    |    |    |
|  G |  I |  T |  ! |    |  R |              |  H |         |  S |  E |  Z |  Y |  O |  U |
|____|____|____|____|    |____|______________|____|____     |____|____|____|____|____|____|
                         |13  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |                   |    |
                         |  Y |  E |  A |  H |  ? |  ! |    |  H |                   |  X |
                         |____|____|____|____|____|____|    |____|                   |____|
                                             |    |
                                             |  ! |
                                             |____|
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based off of Mike Q's answer, another way to phrase the pun would be:

> Cross word puzzle

The pun is:

> A pun between cross (intersect) and cross (angry or upset).
>  With *Crossword puzzle* being a puzzle in which the words cross, a *cross word puzzle* is one in which the words *are* cross.
>
>  This rebus fits both definitions, so you could say it's a cross between the two.

I am a little down that I did not come across the pun before reading Mike's answer.

Comment: Huray, Apep, I'll bounty [Mike Q's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/55490/18129) to ease both of our consciences, as you clearly meant to give away this answer there, in a comment, for almost a day

Answer (score 7):

I think three-word pun is...

> **CROSS WORD CROSSWORD**

As in

> A crossword (by appearance), where the theme are "cross words", where the term "cross" means "angry". This includes words and phrases related to being angry, expletives, or things said during an argument.

Comment: And here I was, trying to find a third word to go with the first two to imply multiple meanings. :\  I may post anyway.

Comment: Pebff jbeq chmmyr is another possibility.

Comment: ^ even better. You should post.

Comment: @Apep That's a good idea. Post it as a new answer!